# don't show photos after production in next.js

Tags: node.js, next.js

I made an application with Next.js and used node.js in the api part. I had no problems using it on my own computer, but when I run it on my server in digitalocean, the photos I uploaded from the administration panel are not shown. When I check the database and directory, there is no problem. The photo is being recorded there.  section is correct when I enter the site and check it. When I wear path / file.jpg it gives 404 error.

There is no problem in the previous recordings and it shows the photos. The photos do not show after running on the server.

I made folder permissions 777, but nothing else came to my mind. I didn't add code because I didn't think there was a problem with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows: It started to work after defining express static files into the API.